# app crash when click on textfield of uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Anyone know how to solve. my question is that when I click on textfield of uiwebview app was crashing.

**error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please file a radar on
>   UIKit with this log if you see this assertion. selectorString =
>   setTitle:, exercisedImplementations = {"setTitle:" =();}'

Comment: Please post some code which you have tried already

Comment: Sounds like you need to file a radar on UIKit. Please note here which macOS, Xcode, and iOS version you have used.